# MVC - DropDown containing all distinct values for one field in database?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown list that contains all distinct values for ONE column (field) from my database by using the `Model` in my view.

I'm actually not sure what the `Model` is normally called, but apparently it's NOT a ViewModel. This is the `Model` I'm referring to:

`@model IEnumerable<Model.Student>`

The field that I need is `Company`. I'm new to MVC and not sure where to begin so all suggestions are appreciated.

I've also been searching other questions, but can't find one that solves my problem.

**Edit:** I'm coding in C#, ASP.Net 4.5 and using Razor views.

Comment: Would be helpful if you told us what language you're using.

Comment: there are different type of method, you can try this one [Bind dropdownlist in mvc4 razor](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
<select id="company" name="company">
    @foreach(var c in Model.Select(s => s.Company).Distinct())
    {
        <option id="c-@count">@c</option>
    }
</select>
```