# ASP.NET MVC Select Distinct Values into Dropdown for filter, retain values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a basic MVC Index view with a simple textbox for searching and it works fine. I wanted to add a dropdownlist filter as well to pull distinct values from one of the fields. I got it working by using an article like this:

[MVC - DropDown containing all distinct values for one field in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993777/mvc-dropdown-containing-all-distinct-values-for-one-field-in-database)

You just loop through the distinct values in your model. The problem is, once you've selected a value and the form submits, it filters just fine, but now the dropdownlist only contains ONE values (the current one selected) because now your view is filtered.

Is there a simple way to keep the original values or to use Razor in the view to tell it to re-search your model with no filters in order to populate the dropdownlist?

here's part of the view

```
@model IEnumerable<KPI_OnlineBilling_MVC.Models.OBProjectRequisition>

 @Html.DropDownList("region", new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.MMRegion).Distinct().ToList()), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

and the controller is basically

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string Regions)
{
var requisitions = from s in db.OBProjectRequisitions select s;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Regions))
{
requisitions = requisitions.Where(s => s.MMRegion.Contains(Regions));
}

return View(requisitions.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Can you post part of your code? Like the controller part and the view?

Comment: You need to generate your `SelectList` in the controller method by generating the values from the database table containing the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to refill the model (or viewdata) in exactly the same way as you did on your initial view action.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what I did was add this in the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Regions", "* ALL")
```

In the controller I made sure one of the paramters what "string Regions" that way the selected value comes through as a string and I can filter on it.

```
var regions = new SelectList(
db.ModelStuffs.Select(r => r.Region).Distinct().OrderBy(Region => Region).ToList(), Regions);

ViewBag.Regions = regions;
```

Yea yea yea. I know people hate using viewbag, but it was the easiest way to have the data pass to the view, otherwise filtering data based on the view itself causes one the current filtered item to show up in the dropdown

That last "Regions" argument sets the selected value for the list so when it's rendered in the view, it automatically selects the last value you selected

I'm not really sure what kind of problems people have with using the viewbag for something like this. It's better than using any sort of TempData object because the latter will cause issues if you're working with multiple tabs/windows. For a non-heavily used internal app, this seems to work fine.